# Where are XP calculations handed in AzerothCore

Tags: azerothcore

I am looking to rebuild the XP calculations for my build, changing them to have linear scaling as you level up, with notable increases for killing things above your level. I know the formula I would like to use, but I cannot seem to find where the calculations are handled in AzerothCore.

If anyone could point me to the correct class, or even better, correct method within the class it would be much appreciated.

Comment: You could make a recursive search in the src code (grep on linux) for the config option from worldserver.conf, then follow the tracks until you get to the code.

Answer (score 0):

Found it, its actually scattered over several classes, with 
quest XP in questDef.cpp uint32 Quest::XPValue(Player* player) const on line 175

Kill XP calculations are in Formulas.h what I want to edit is the formula in BaseGain on line 103

It is also worth noting that someone by the name of "pussywizard" removed the script manager calls on XP calculations for optimization. they are just commented out, but would need to be restored for any module that needs them.